# How to get the exist cluster by name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I am using `CDK` and would like to use the exist cluster(for ECS)

I try this, however it shows,

error such as `Property 'fromClusterName' does not exist on type 'typeof Cluster'. Did you mean 'fromClusterArn'?`

```
const clusterName = "mycluster"
const cluster = ecs.Cluster.fromClusterName(this, "StCluster", {
  clusterName: clusterName
});
```

Yet, I want to get the cluster by `name` not `arn`

I guess I should take `arn` by name in advance?

I am cheking this document, there is no method to get `Cluster` by name

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs.Cluster.html

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`fromClusterAttributes`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs.Cluster.html#static-fromwbrclusterwbrattributesscope-id-attrs) but you will also need to have the `vpc` the cluster is in. You can import it if you know the `vpc id`.

`fromClusterAttributes` is preferred over `fromClusterArn` as it also gives access to the `vpc` and other properties.

```js
const clusterName = "mycluster";
const vpcID = "12345abcde";

const myVpc = ec2.Vpc.fromVpcAttributes(this, "iVPC", {
  vpcId: vpcID,
// For example
  availability_zones: ["us-east-1a"]
});

const cluster = ecs.Cluster.fromClusterAttributes(this, "iCluster", {
  vpc: myVpc,
  clusterName: clusterName
});
```

Comment: THank you very much!!! I need to add the `SecurityGroups: []` and it works! This artilcle is about this problem https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/11146

Comment: Happy to help! Looks like you may be on an older version of `aws-cdk-lib` since `securityGroups` is `Optional` since `2.85.0`.